# POST Axios request using Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, redis, axios, php-7, laravel-echo

I'm currently using [Laravel@5.5](https://laravel.com) with [Redis](https://redis.io), [laravel-echo-server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server) and [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) and trying to make a realtime chat feature.
I'm not using [vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) as frontend framework.

I'm having some problems when make a POST request using axios and jquery, this :

```
-> echo.js 
 $('#submit').click(function() {
 var content = $('#content').val();    
 axios.post('/api/conversation/update', {   
 content: content });  
});


-> api.php
    Route::post('/conversation/update', 'ConversationController@update');


-> bootstrap.js
   /**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';


/**
 * Next we will register the CSRF Token as a common header with Axios so that
 * all outgoing HTTP requests automatically have it attached. This is just
 * a simple convenience so we don't have to attach every token manually.
 */

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

Output this :

> POST http://localhost:8000/api/conversation/update 401 (Unauthorized)
>   Uncaught (in promise)
>   Error: Request failed with status code 401

I've make many try and research, even with [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport), and don't see where i'm stuck.

Kind regards,
JeuneApprenti.

Comment: Your `/api` routes use the `auth:api` guard. So you must have a token provided by passport for this to work. Show us your passport configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case someone really need an answer there, I finally switched using axios for simple [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) method and set up a socket.io-client

It looks like this :

```
-> echo.js   
const fetchApi = async function (url, options = {}) {
  let response = await fetch(url, {
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
      'Acccept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-Socket-ID': Echo.socketId(),
    },
    ...options
  })
  if (response.ok) {
    return response.json()
  } else {
    throw await response.json()
  }
}

-> api.php

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {
  Route::get('/conversations', 'Api\ConversationController@index');
  Route::get('/conversations/{user}', 'Api\ConversationController@show')   
   ->middleware('can:talkTo,user');
  Route::post('/conversations/{user}', 'Api\ConversationController@store') 
   ->middleware('can:talkTo,user');
});

-> bootstrap.js

import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'socket.io',
  host: window.location.hostname + ':6001',
});
window.io = require('socket.io-client');
```

Then, you can call this script in your views to get datas from websockets via socket.io :

```
<script src="//{{ Request::getHost() }}:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```